# Vba fire onclick event with no IDs or Tags

Tags: javascript, html, vba, onclick

I am trying to Fire an Onclick event using VisualBasic, however, the onclick event does not appear to have any tags or names, just the onclick event itself. Therefore, I am not sure how to fire its onclick event. Posted below are the HTML of the onclick event. The line of code where i am not sure how to create is this appIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("?????").FireEvent .

```
Sub GoToWebsiteTest()

Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "http://websitename"
With appIE
    .Navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set objCollection = appIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
Set objElement = appIE.Document.GetElementById("menulink33")
objElement.Click

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

appIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")("participantId").Value = "XXXXXXXXX"
Set objElement = appIE.Document.GetElementById("searchBtn")
objElement.Click
Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set objElement = appIE.Document.GetElementById("dtcTotalRootInd")
objElement.Click

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

appIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("?????").FireEvent

Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.ReadyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

End Sub
```

Here is the HTML of the onclick im trying to fire.

```
<a onclick="javascript:app.part.submitLink('D','Activity Balance','470993367.62','565573414.24','94580046.62','P')" href="#">
Activity Balance</a>
```

I am not too familiar with HTML so please let me know if i can provide anymore detail. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: have you tried get elements by tag of a, with innertext of Activity Balance, and using fireevent() ?

Comment: Hi nathan, I am not familiar with the inner text? What would that code look like?

Also i tired this code
`For Each l In appIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")`

`If l.href = "#" Then`

    `i.Click`

    `End If`

But it didnt work.

Comment: if l.innerText = "Activity Balance" then l.click are you using I?  or .FireEvent()

Comment: I tried both 

If l.InnerText = "Activity Balance" Then
i.FireEvent 


If l.InnerText = "Activity Balance" Then
i.Click

neither errored but neither worked

Comment: look at FireEvent on google you have to specify the event i.e. "click"

Comment: Nathan, Ive tried to persevere with the Inner Text but cant seem to get it to work. Do you know the syntax to fire the event in the onclick. Google seems to be conflicting. Thanks for your help

Comment: did you see this? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hey Nathan I was able to figure it out! The inner Text had a space before the text like this " Activity Balance". The space wouldnt even show when i copied the text directly from the HTML. I ended up looping through the tags and then just doing a tagx.click. Thanks so much for your help mate. I appreciate it.

Comment: No probs, it's good to use trim(string), when comparing things like this. :)  Also, having the locals window open can assist greatly :) Glad you persevered though and cracked it.